# Multiple apache server on Mac OS X. How to remove extra server?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I'm using macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.3) and using build in apache server. I've tried to upgrade php version to 7.2 few month ago. Today I noticed I've multiple httpd.conf file. When I run:

`# locate httpd.conf`

Output is as bellow:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous
/private/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.29_1/.bottle/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.29_1/.bottle/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf.bak
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/original/httpd.conf
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/usr/local/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
```

When I try to restart server using: `# apachectl restart` It's not work. I've to run `# /usr/sbin/apachectl restart` to restart the server.

I'm confused which is my original server. How do I detect which is my original server and how to remove all other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current working apache server by running any one of these command in terminal:

`httpd -V` or `apachectl -V`